# React native in app pucrchase subscription with apple pay

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

Due to recent changes, Apple is not accepting Stripe as a vendor for In-app purchases.
I'm trying to implement an In-App purchase with `expo-in-app-purchases` but not being able to have the payment show Apple pay.

Is there any instruction on how I can allow apple pay using `expo-in-app-purchases` ?

Comment: Apple has never accepted stripe for in app purchase. In app purchases don't use Apple Pay directly. In app purchases are processed by apple's backend using the payment method associated with the users App Store account.

Comment: @Paulw11 during my last implementation with the in-app purchase, Apple reproved the build claiming the Apple pay wasn't in place. The build has in-app purchase and apple pay set on the build capabilities (xcode). Still wasn't able to use Apple pay with `expo-in-app-purchases` . How I can make Apple pay available using In app purchase on React native ? I could do it with Stripe payment  library

Comment: Are you selling real world physical goods or services or are you selling digital goods or services delivered in the app?  If the second then you simply use Storekit and Apple processes the payment. You don't need to,worry about Apple Pay.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your answer. I'll try to submit my build again to have it In-app on iOS. To answer your question: I'm selling a subscription service within the app, no physical goods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the last interaction, I've removed the `merchantId` from xcode , and push a new build only with `in-app-purchase`. Apple submission were approved and I no longer have this issue.